# Is it possible to cancel file upload that uses hidden iframe?

Tags: ajax, iframe, file-upload, upload

Is it possible to cancel file upload that uses hidden iframe?

I've tried to set source of iframe to empty string, but upload haven't been interrupted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the iframe is the transport channel that is carrying the form posting, so Atanas is correct, you have to stop the transport inside the iframe.

here is a way of doing it depending on browser:

```
if (iframeObj.contentWindow.document.execCommand)
    { // IE browsers
        iframeObj.contentWindow.document.execCommand('Stop');
    }
else
    { // other browsers
        iframeObj.contentWindow.stop();
    }
// notify user upload was cancelled, remove spinner images, etc
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
iframe.contentWindow.stop(); //for anything but IE
iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand("Stop"); // for IE
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i guess removing the iframe from the dom should be enough?

Answer (score 0):

Currenty setting iframe src to "javascript:false" works for me.